# Which Divya Prabandham commentators discussed this Kishkindha Kanda verse?

Tags: ramayana, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, alwar, divya-prabhandham

In the beginning of the Kishkindha Kanda of the Valmiki Ramayana, Rama and Lakshmana reach the banks of the lake Pampa, and Rama laments as all the beautiful things he sees around him reminds of Sita, who has just been kidnapped by Ravana.  In particular, he says [this](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga1/kishkindha_1_frame.htm):

> padma kesara saṃsṛṣṭo vṛkṣāntara viniḥsṛtaḥ | 
>   niḥśvāsa iva sītāyā vāti vāyuḥ manoharaḥ ||
>
> Like Sita's sighs, the captivating wind blows, passing through the trees after mingling with lotus filaments.

Now Govindaraja, the Sri Vaishanava commentator on the Valmiki Ramayana, says [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=_sU1y6gYZIgC&lpg=PA201&ots=w2CsNPatKj&dq=%22has%20been%20commented%20upon%20by%20the%20authors%20of%20the%20commentary%20on%20the%22&pg=PA201#v=onepage&q&f=false) about this verse:

> This shloka has been commented upon by the authors of the commentary on the Dravidopanishad.

For those who don’t know, Dravida Upanishad, or “South Indian Upanishad”, is a term used to refer the Naalayira Divya Prabandham, the collected poems of the Alwars which are central scriptures in the Sri Vaishnava sect.

So my question is, which commentators of the Naalayira Divya Prabandham discuss this Kishkindha Kanda verse?  Numerous Sri Vaishnava Acharyas have written commentaries on various parts of the Naalayira Divya Prabandham; here are some of the commentaries just on Nammalwar’s Thiruvaimozhi:

1. Thirukurugai Piran Pillan’s 6000 Padi
2. Nanjiyar’s 9000 Padi
3. Vadikesari Azhagiya Manavala Perumal Jeeyar’s 12000 Padi
4. Periyavachan Pillai’s 24000 Padi
5. Vadakku Thiruveedhi Pillai’s Eedu

And Periyavachan Pillai also wrote commentaries for most of the rest of the Naalayira Divya Prabandham.

So which of these, if any, discuss this Kishkindha Kanda verse?  Are there any subcommentaries on Govindaraja’s commentary which shed light on this?

Comment: see Pasurappadi Ramayanam